# Not able to mousehover (movetoElement) using actions class

Tags: java, selenium, action, selenium3

AM using below code and trying to mousehover on a link. code is getting executed successfully without any errors but i couldnt see any action on the web page.

**system specifications:**
Windows 7;
mozilla 52.0 64 bit;
selenium 3.3.0

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;


public class Mouseaction {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setenter code hereProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Selenium\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");           
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Electronics")).isDisplayed());
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Electronics"))).build().perform();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working. I tested the below code and it works.

```
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
WebElement link = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[title='Electronics']")));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(link).build().perform();
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but it is not working for me.

Comment: I have tried the above code and its still not working. And it is also not throwing any error. Does the action class work in below system specifications?
system specifications: Windows 7; mozilla 52.0 64 bit; selenium 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try using chrome driver

And below is the complete working code  :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Mouseaction {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[text()='Electronics']")).isDisplayed());
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[text()='Electronics']"))).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(12000);

        System.out.println(
                "HoverOver successfull on : " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[text()='Electronics']")));
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
true

HoverOver successfull on : [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (1e433b044b5162e96df55c46690dd943)] -> xpath: //a/span[text()='Electronics']]
```

Comment: I have tried the above code and its still not working. And it is also not throwing any error. Does the action class work in below system specifications?
system specifications: Windows 7; mozilla 52.0 64 bit; selenium 3.3.0

Comment: I updated the code , please try this . It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Your locator isn't working, try this:

```
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");           

    WebElement hoverOn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a"));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(hoverOn).build().perform();
```

Comment: Using any locator with that many nested levels is not a good practice. It makes it brittle.

Comment: I have tried the above code and its still not working. And it is also not throwing any error. Does the action class work in below system specifications?
system specifications: Windows 7; mozilla 52.0 64 bit; selenium 3.3.0